# Automated tag additions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Recently I started to edit the tags of questions because they often miss crucial parts like [marketing-cloud]. Is there an option to set these kind of attributes automated?

Some examples where you could set the tag [marketing-cloud] this is when a question has the one of these tags:

- Content-Builder
- Personalization-Builder
- Automation-Studio
- AmpScript
- GTL / SSJS (most likely)
- Email-Studio
- Contactbuilder
- Journeybuilder
- ... (many others)

I started to edit those but quickly ran against the edit limit a user has. But based on those attributes you could nearly always set the tag [marketing-cloud].

I believe there are other tags of other salesforce products where you can also apply this logic. For example lightning will be most likely salescloud?

Is there such an option on SFSE and if who can develop / automate it?

Answer (score 5):

I believe there is no way to automate such tag additions. You can create a `tag-synonym`, but that would simply *replace* `content-builder` with `marketing-cloud`, which is not what you want here.

Comment: I believe this is the solution for now, but i keep this question open. Maybe it will be possible in the future? Can you somehow request or generate ideas for that, that stackoverflow might implement it? ;)