# Can you make a tag mandatory to set?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I recently [asked](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2909/automated-tag-additions) if an automation can be implemented which would add certain tags if other specific tags have been set. Since it is not possible to implement I have a different approach i would like to ask. With the implementation it should be always clear which salesforce product the person is mainly talking/questioning about.

Since recently has been talked about "badge-hammers" this might even be a sideproduct that should be implemented to correctly track a persons contribution to a salesforce product.

- Is it possible to declare a new tag like "Salesforce Product Tag"
  which is mandatory and only allows one tag attribute?
- Just like a dropdown where you can only select "marketing-cloud",
  "salescloud", "service-cloud", "pardot", "datorama", "...", but only
  those. Moderators configure these tags.

Remember: There needs to be a solution for all the questions that already have existed before the change.

Comment: I don't think moderators could do this, even if they wanted to. I think you would need the actual devs behind the stack to make changes like this.

Answer (score 4):

Having one blanket tag is a terrible idea that we have already done away with. It [took us considerable effort](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2227/2995) to get rid of the `[salesforce-crm]` tag. I have no desire to bring it back.

Comment: Moderators would not create that tag. What i ment in my post was that there can only be valid options (like from a dropdown list) that moderators configure

Comment: For guys like me (currently) cannot contribute anything to stuff that has to do with salesforce crm, therefore you would really like to ignore that tag and "subscribe" or watch on the marketing-cloud tag. But i also understand that having a non informative tag may be bad in some situations. It really matters on the point of view.

Comment: You already *can* subscribe to the existing `[marketing-cloud]` tag. You could also subscribe to `[data-extensions]`, etc.

Comment: Of course I can but I cannot ignore [salescloud] [service-cloud] [pardot] etc. because these tags will not ever be set for sales cloud or servicecloud. These just tend to have lightning, lightning components or whatever but you then cannot judge between Einstein Marketing Cloud and Einstein salescloud or stuff like it, because the users of those systems just not set those attributes, while Marketing Cloud users always have to set the tag marketing-cloud? Isn’t this exactly what you experienced with salesforce crm? Will Marketing Cloud be deleted soon then? (Exaggerated not meant personal)

Comment: The more products Salesforce will own and add to their ecosystem the more it will become complex when you do not differentiate the systems and have equal naming in the different products. Just like analytics, tracking, Einstein, recommendations, ... from my opinion we should start to invest into a system where it’s always clear which product of Salesforce the questions are about. For me it’s something that is becoming increasingly unclear.

Comment: I think we are going to have to agree to disagree here.